# Unable get the value of textarea inside jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I tried to put a textarea inside a dialog box and what I want is to get the value of that textarea if "ok" is click but I can't get the value. What might be the problem?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#open', function () {
    var txt = $('#txt').val();
    $('#break-diag').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Dialog',
        show: {
            effect: "scale",
            duration: 200
        },
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: "ok",
            click: function () {
                console.log(txt);
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#break-diag{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="open">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="break-diag">
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Textareas don't have a `value` attribute. Instead, they use `innerHTML` for storing it. Try accesing it using `$('#txt').html();` or `$('#txt').text();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are capturing the textarea value on click of open; which would be empty during this event.

The value should be captured on click of Ok

```
click: function () {
       var txt = $('#txt').val();
       console.log(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the text when the dialogue opens. There's no text there, yet.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#open', function () {
    $('#break-diag').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Dialog',
        show: {
            effect: "scale",
            duration: 200
        },
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: "ok",
            click: function () {
                var txt = $('#txt').val();
                console.log(txt);
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#break-diag{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="open">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="break-diag">
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#open', function () { 
    $('#break-diag').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Dialog',
        show: {
            effect: "scale",
            duration: 200
        },
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: "ok",
            click: function () {
              var text=  $('#txt').val();
                alert(text);
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the CSS style **display:none** with #break-diag DIV.

so how can you imagine that anything can be display.

so when you click on the button, **display:none** property should be removed from **#break-diag DIV**.